# Bing Maps Infobox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, maps, bing-maps, bing

I have created multiple `infoboxes` using **BingMaps** V8 API.

The issue that I am facing here is when the `infobox` is towards the corners of the map, the details from `infobox` is trimmed.

infobox being trimmed. I want to autopan the :

[image]

**Code :**

```
    var ParseLatLogXml = function(xml, address){
    if(typeof xml.resourceSets["0"].resources === "undefined" || xml.resourceSets["0"].resources.length === 0)
    {
    console.log("Lat Long of Address not found: " + address);
     return [];
    }

    return [ xml.resourceSets["0"].resources["0"].geocodePoints["0"].coordinates["0"], 
                 xml.resourceSets["0"].resources["0"].geocodePoints["0"].coordinates["1"] ];
    };

    var AddStore = function( storeNumb ,storeID, storeName, city, state, addr, phone, zip, distance, lat, long){

    var _loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(long));
    var _pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(_loc, { 

                                                        icon: '-/media/1044109b112b479bb98e4daf6154e817.ashx',
                                                        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(20, 20) 
                                                    }
    );
    var adder = addr + '\r\n' + city + '\r\n' + zip + state + "\r\n" + storeName
     // Create the infobox for the pushpin
    var _infoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(_pin.getLocation(),
    {   width: 300,
     height: 150,
    title: storeName,
    description:  distance + " miles" +'<br>' + addr +'<br>'+ city + " "+ zip +'<br>'+ phone ,
    offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10,15),
    showCloseButton: false,
    visible: false
    });

    // Add handler for the pushpin click event.

    // Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(_pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(_pin, 'mouseover', function () {
    _infoBox.setOptions({ autoPan:true, visible: true });
    });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(_pin, 'mouseout', function () {
    _infoBox.setOptions({  autoPan:true, visible: false });
              });

map.entities.push(_pin); //[locNum]
        _infoBox.setMap(map);
```

I tried using the auto pan which i am not sure if it would do the trick.
Can someone help me on this.

I also tried the re-positioning of the `ifobox` and that `dinot` help either.

I used below links for reference :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cf803dd2-0f56-429e-863b-9f9a6480ff17/bing-maps-v8-api-repositioning-an-infobox?forum=bingmapsajax

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in autopan or repositioning logic in the Infobox class in Bing Maps. The easiest solution would be to center the map on the pushpin when opening the infobox, although this would be better suited if using a click event to open the infobox rather than a mouseover event. Using mouseover/mouseout events would result in the infobox closing if the infoboxes position was changed.

Another option is to use the Custom Infobox module here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control The infobox in this module repositions how it is displayed based on where in the map the pushpin is. If the pushpin is in the top right corner, the infobox displays itself to the bottom left of the pushpin. You can find the source code for this module here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BMv7Plugins/BMv7.CustomInfobox/scripts/V7CustomInfobox.js

Comment: This doesn't apply to v8, I can't seem to find a workaround for v8 either. The suggested solution is for v7.

Comment: That module works with v8 too. Most of those v7 modules do. V8 is over 90% backwards compatible. There is a table on that module site that lists which ones have been tested against v8.